# DDD entity shared between two apps

Tags: domain-driven-design

Say I have an object that for the most part has necessary attributes, etc for two different apps because both apps have the need to use them. It's possible that 10% of the attributes won't' be used in one app. Is it better to share that object (and aggregate/bounded context as a shared kernel?) or duplicate the attributes and data that is stored? One app is for end users/activities and the other app is for the management of the users/activities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An entity is typically not shared between BCs.  You may have another BC in play.  You should have one BC that is the system of record for the entity.  All other BCs should be *downstream* from it and contain only the identity and relevant bits of data.  Typically one would employ an event-driven architecture to notify dependent systems of any relevant changes to the state of the entity in question.

It may also be that you are trying to split a single BC.  Perhaps focus on the BC side of things as opposed to the technical/application side.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 7):

We recently developed an application that involved several modules using a lot of common entities. When we developed them, we moved these common entities to a project called common-domain and then had all the dependent modules use it. It turned out to be a disaster.

While we initially found several attributes to be common, we found out that how we designed them for certain modules conflicted in how they were used for the others. Altering the entities in the common-domain to fit the needs of one module sometimes broke how they worked for the other modules. We did not use a test-driven approach and it made finding the resulting bugs tedious.

Learning from that mistake, we should have recognized and identified the bounded contexts and identified the entities and their associated attributes per bounded context. The "common" entity should have been defined per bounded context along with any attribures that are needed for that context. Some attributes will definitely be common but since they are separate bounded contexts, they have to be declared per entity per bounded context.

I'll go a little bit further to mention where an item can be shared. Each entity in a bounded context has its own repository. It is possible that the "common" entities share the same underlying database table. It is the responsibility of each BC's entity repository to retrieve the relevant columns in order to return the appropriate entity instance.